# Website multi language, but i need to change location of directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-handling

I have a question about php and .htaccess.
I try to make my first php website with multi language. The language changer is work, but i get one problem, when i try change the page (homapage to about us for example...).

In the href i use this:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="index.php?lang='.$_GET['lang'].'/about_us">'.$lang['about_us'].'</a>
```

In .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pages

RewriteRule ^(hu|en)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1?lang=hu [L,QSA]
```

The script write this error line:

```
include(lang/en/about_us/lang.en/about_us.php): failed to open stream
```

The location of the language files:

[image: 1]

The location of the pages files:
[image: 2]

Can you help me?

Comment: The format is wrong, since lang would become `en/about_us`. You probably need `href="about_us?lang='.$_GET['lang'].'"`

Comment: I change something in php (wrong url switch, and other) and now it's work.